# Making bash output a certain word from a .txt file

Tags: bash

I have a question on Bash:

Like the title says, I require bash to output a certain word, depending on where it is in the file. In my explicit example I have a simple .txt file.

I already found out that you can count the number of words within a file with the command:

```
wc -w < myFile.txt
```

An output example would be:

```
78501
```

There certainly is also a way to make "cat" to only show word number x. Something like:

```
cat myFile.txt | wordno. 3125
desired-word
```

Notice, that I will welcome any command, that gets this done, not only cat.

Alternatively or in addition, I would be happy to know how you can make certain characters in a file show, based on their place in it. Something like:

```
cat myFile.txt | characterno. 2342
desired-character
```

I already know how you can achieve this with a variable:

```
a="hello, how are you"
echo ${a:9:1}
w
```

Only problem is a variable can only be so long. Is it as long as a whole .txt file, it won't work.

I look forward to your answers!

Comment: Sorry but it is not at all clear, please do add more information and let us know then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `awk`for this job it splits the string at spaces and prints the `$wordnumber` stringpart and `tr` is used to remove newlines

```
cat myFile.txt | tr -d '\n' | awk -v wordnumber=5 '{ print $wordnumber }'
```

And if you want the for example 5th. character you could do this like so

```
head -c 5 myFile.txt | tail -c 1
```

Comment: @wiomoc, you need not to use these many commands for this, it could be easily handled by `awk`. `awk` could read file itself.

Comment: note: you can use `tr -d '\n' < myFile.txt | awk ...`. Input redirection is supported by all shells. Besides that, unless the lines are wrapped in the input file you want `tr '\n' ' '` instead of `-d`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have NOT shown samples of Input_file or expected output so couldn't test it. You could simply do this with `awk` as follows could be an example.

```
awk 'FNR==1{print substr($0,2342,1);next}' Input_file
```

Where we are telling `awk` to look for 1st line `FNR==1` and in `substr` where we tell `awk` to take character `2342` and next `1` means from that position take only 1 character you could increase its value or keep it as per your need too.

Answer (score 0):

With gawk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[[:space:]]+"} NR==12345' file
```

or

```
gawk 'NR==12345' RS="[[:space:]]+" file
```

I'm setting the *record separator* to a sequences of *spaces* which includes newlines and then print the `12345`th record.

To improve the average performance you can exit the script once the match is found:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS="[[:space:]]+"}NR==12345{print;exit}' file
```